# Having issues deploying my React APP to Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

I've "successfully" deployed my React APP to heroku, but I'm having issues with starting it.

This is what I get as an error

```
2022-06-04T19:38:15.706703+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2022-06-04T19:38:17.279180+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Missing script: "start"
```

Now I get that this is because of my package.json, the start script looks like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
```

I'm confused as to what I'm supposed to put for the start script, do I put the route for my App.js? If I do that it tells me "Cannot use import statement outside a module".

Your help would be SUPER appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What did you use to create your react app? Is it create-react-app  or is it vite?
Because they have their own start command script for it.

Comment: hey @Ensar, it's create-react-app

Comment: I forgot to add that, the start works within my client folder (where my react application is), but I had to push my root folder (so outside my react application) to heroku. Which is why the start is empty

Answer (score 0):

For create-react-app you should add your `package.json` file

```
"start":"react-scripts start"
```

For more info you could check [this](https://dev.to/smithmanny/deploy-your-react-app-to-heroku-2b6f).

Comment: Hey there, thank you but this is for typical react apps, my react app works when I use npm start inside the client folder, but heroku wants to open my react app outside my client folder, in the root folder

Comment: Have you tried to give a path like `"start" : "cd my-app-folder/ | react-scripts start"`
Maybe that could work.

Comment: yea doesn't work though :/